# How can I merge two DataFrames based on a filtered sum?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two DataFrames that look like this

```
   start_date    end_date
1  2018-01-01  2018-01-31
2  2018-01-15  2018-02-28
3  2018-01-31  2018-03-15
4  2018-01-07  2018-04-30

            value
2018-01-01      1
2018-01-02      4
2018-01-03      2
2018-01-04     10
2018-01-05      0
...           ...
2018-12-28      1
2018-12-29      7
2018-12-30      9
2018-12-31      5
```

I'm trying to add a new column to the first DataFrame that contains the summed values of the second DataFrame, filtered by `start_date` and `end_date`. Something like

```
   start_date    end_date  total_value
1  2018-01-01  2018-01-31           47  # Where 47 is the sum of values between 2018-01-01 and 2018-01-31, inclusive
2  2018-01-15  2018-02-28           82
3  2018-01-31  2018-03-15          116
4  2018-01-07  2018-04-30          253
```

I think I can do this with `apply` (basically just filter and sum the second DataFrame by `start_date` and `end_date` and return the sum), but I'm wondering if there's a neat pandas-esque solution instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### NEW ANSWER

I'm using OP data and it needs to be massaged slightly

```
df2 = df2.asfreq('D').fillna(0, downcast='infer')
```

Then we do the `cumsum` thing with an added shift.

```
s = df2.value.cumsum()
starts = df1.start_date.map(s.shift().fillna(0, downcast='infer'))
ends = df1.end_date.map(s)

df1.assign(total_value=ends - starts)

  start_date   end_date  total_value
1 2018-01-01 2018-01-31           17
2 2018-01-15 2018-02-28            0
3 2018-01-31 2018-03-15            0
4 2018-01-07 2018-04-30            0
```

---

### OLD ANSWER

COOL, but inaccurate.  This is the sum of numbers after the start date.  In order to include start date, I have to use shift.  See above.

You can use `cumsum` and take differences.

```
df1.assign(
    total_value=df1.applymap(df2.cumsum().value.get).eval('end_date - start_date'))

  start_date   end_date  total_value
1 2018-01-01 2018-01-31          145
2 2018-01-15 2018-02-28          229
3 2018-01-31 2018-03-15          212
4 2018-01-07 2018-04-30          535
```

---

### Setup

```
np.random.seed([3, 1415])

min_date = df1.values.min()
max_date = df1.values.max()
tidx = pd.date_range(min_date, max_date)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict(value=np.random.randint(10, size=len(tidx))), tidx)
```

Answer (score 3):

***Setup***

```
df2.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Create your conditions using a loop and `zip` (It's important that `output` matches the index of your `df1`)

```
conditions = [df2['index'].between(i, j) for i, j in zip(df1.start_date, df1.end_date)]
output = df1.index
```

Use `np.select`, then `groupby`:

```
tmp = df2.assign(flag=np.select(conditions, output, np.nan))
tmp = tmp.dropna().groupby('flag').value.sum()
```

Finally merge:

```
df1.merge(tmp.to_frame(), left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Output:

```
    start_date   end_date  value
1.0 2018-01-01 2018-01-31     17
```

Answer (score 2):

Notice this will be O(m*n) method , create a new key for merge

```
df1['Newkey']=1    
df2['Newkey']=1    
df2.reset_index(inplace=True)    
mergefilterdf=df1.merge(df2).\
                loc[lambda  x : (x['start_date']<=x['index'])&(x['end_date']>=x['index'])]
mergefilterdf.groupby(['start_date','end_date']).value.sum()
Out[331]: 
start_date  end_date  
2018-01-01  2018-01-31    17
Name: value, dtype: int64
```